# If I make a ranged attack at a paralyzed creature within 5 feet of me, do I have advantage on the roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, ranged-attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

**If I cast *guiding bolt* at a paralyzed creature while standing within 5 feet of it (so it counts as a critical hit), do I have advantage on the roll?**

The rule on ["Ranged Attacks in Close Combat"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#RangedAttacksinCloseCombat) says (PHB, p. 195; emphasis mine):

> When you make a ranged attack [...], you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who you can see and **who isn't incapacitated**.

Therefore, since the creature *is* incapacitated, I will not have disadvantage on the attack despite being within 5 feet of the enemy.

In fact, I should be rolling with advantage since I'm hitting a paralyzed foe, as stated in the rules for the [paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed) condition (PHB, p. 291; emphasis mine):

> - A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) and can’t move or speak.
> - The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
> - **Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.**
> - **Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.**

Am I correctly understanding the rules here?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. If you found one of the answers to be the most helpful in [answering your question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), you should click the checkmark icon to the left of it in order to accept it as the best solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a question. Why would you not have advantage?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 18):

#### You have advantage.

The rules for [ranged attacks in close combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#RangedAttacksinCloseCombat) state:

> Aiming a ranged attack is more difficult when a foe is next to you. When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who can see you and **who isn't incapacitated**.

Since a [paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed) creature is incapacitated, the above rule does not apply, so your ranged attack will be at advantage, even from 5 feet away (unless there's also a different enemy 5 feet away from you who isn’t incapacitated).

Comment: @SampleText If an answer solves your problem, you can mark it “accepted” by clicking the green check beneath the vote buttons.

Answer (score 8):

#### Your understanding of the rules is correct, you have advantage

First off, the target is [paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed) which means, in part, that:

> [...] Attack rolls against the creature have advantage. [...]

This applies to *any* attack rolls, be they melee or ranged or from any distance whatsoever.

Meanwhile the rules on [Ranged Attacks in Close Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#RangedAttacksinCloseCombat) state:

> [...] When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who can see you and who isn't incapacitated.

So if you're making a ranged attack and a hostile creature is within 5 feet of you (regardless of whether or not they are the target) **and** they are not incapacitated, you have disadvantage.

However, in this case, they *are* incapacitated because part of the paralyzed condition states:

> [...] A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) [...]

Therefore they do *not* cause disadvantage on the ranged attack, meanwhile the paralyzed condition grants advantage so you have a net result of just having advantage.

---

Perhaps of note is what would happen if you had advantage for attacking a paralyzed creature *and* disadvantage because a *non*-incapacitated creature was within 5 feet of you. In this case, you would be considered to have neither advantage nor disadvantage because of the rules on [Advantage and Disadvantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage):

> [...] If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20. [...]